# How to format 18 digit double to become 10 string character

Tags: java, number-formatting, trim

```
double pdouble= 3.3603335204002837E12;

String pstart= Double.toString(pdouble).replace(".", "") .trim()

String.format("%10d", pstart);

System.out.println("pstart"+pstart);
```

Can I know why it not works...
It display this:

> Exception in thread "main"
>         java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String at
>   java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
>   .I

Hope anybody can help

Comment: Format character `d` expects a number, not a string. Let the `format()` do the conversion to string (but with appropriate format character) and remove the dot afterwards.

Comment: You mean like this.. pstart=String.format("%10d", pdouble);
           pstart.replace(".", "")  //remove the left bracket
               .trim();

Comment: Still error and same problem happen

Comment: `d` is wrong format specifier for this. Your code in the comments shouldn't show the same error as in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%d` is for `int`. As `pstart` is a String, Use `b` or `s`.

```
String.format("%10s", pstart);
```

Output

```
33603335204002837E12
```

Read [Java String format()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-format)

---

However if you need only the first 10 digits from your number, try using `DecimalFormat`

```
DecimalFormat d = new DecimalFormat("0000000000");
String number = d.format(pdouble);
```

Output

```
3360333520400
```

This will also add leading `0`s if the number is less than 10 digits.

Comment: Nope I already try..the value become 33603335204002837E12...it just remove the decimal

Comment: @ranjithh You need only the first 10 digits? I've edited my answer. Check

Comment: The result become  33603335204002 still not 10 and when i change only have 9's 0 still it have 12-14 char...or is it the bug in my programme since i need to generate thousand of double?

Answer (score 0):

For decimal numbers "f" flag needs to be used.

```
double pdouble= 3.3603335204002837E12;

System.out.println(String.format("%10f", pdouble));
```

This will print a string with minimum length of 10 chars.

In this pattern "%10f" the width flag (e.g. 10) is the minimum number of characters

> The width is the minimum number of characters to be written to the output. For the line separator conversion, width is not applicable; if it is provided, an exception will be thrown.

from [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) java doc

Comment: The output become like this 3360333520400.2837888; Still not become 10 character and not cut the decimal behind..Thanks anyway